# multiple authentications on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have built in laravel an authentication system on user table.
I have to make two login pages for admin and normal user on same users table.
I have use spatie roles and permission but it does not stop admin login from normal user login page and vice versa.

I have add checkmaster middleware just for accepting my question on stackoverflow.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckMaster
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->hasRole('master')) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('home');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middleware is working only when user try to go in certain route.

Therefore, the middleware `CheckMaster` only takes place when logon user tried to go in certain route.

If you are implementing with `Auth\LoginController.php`, you can override the function `authenticated` when user is authenticated, example code:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->hasRole('master')) {
        return redirect('master-home');
    }

    return redirect('home');
}
```

Comment: i have two login pages localhost/login and localhost/admin/login on same user table.....Is there any way for blocking master login from localhost/login by saying 'these credentials does not match' ...

Comment: Since both login is sharing same login function, it's no harm to redirect master user redirect to master page if they login from /login, but if insist to do so, you can play the trick by checking route in authenticated, eg: `if ($user->hasRole('master') && !$request->is('master/*')) auth()->logout($user)` then redirect user and show error message